# Ways to arrange the integers 1 to 9 with operators so that the result is 100

Tags: code-golf, recursion

## **Prelude:**

This task is taken from [Five Problems Every Software Engineer Should Be Able to Solve in Less Than an Hour](https://gist.github.com/agrison/1a27a50c22a7f46df17c), which I really recommend.

## **The task:**

> Write a program that outputs all possibilities to put + or - or
> nothing between the numbers 1, 2, ..., 9 (in this order) such that the result is always 100.

## **Winning Criteria:**

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Are spaces allowed between the numbers, like `1 2 3+4+5` rather than `123+4+5`?

Comment: Pretty similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3019/getting-an-answer-from-a-string-of-digits (this link allows for `*` & `/` and does not specify the target 100)

Answer (score 13):

## Perl 5.10.0 - <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 45B

```
say for grep{eval==100}glob join'{,+,-}',1..9
```

Usage: `perl -M5.10.0 scratch.pl` (I think I get the version for free)

Comment: A very nice solution; both concise and fairly readable even without much knowledge of Perl.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
"-"SL]8m*{A,2>.+1\+s}%{~]:+100=},N*S/'+*
```

Here is how it works:

```
"-"SL]                     e# This is an array containing -, space and empty character
                           e# This represents -, + and joints correspondingly
      8m*                  e# Get all cartesian products of these 3 strings of length 8
                           e# For instance, all cartesian products of length 2 are:
                           e# [["-" " "] ["-" "-"] ["-" ""] [" " " "] [" " "-"] [" " ""]
                           e# ["" " "] ["" "-"] ["" ""]]
         {          }%     e# Map these cartesian products over this loop
          A,2>             e# Get array [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
              .+           e# In-order concatenation of the above two arrays
                1\+s       e# Prepend 1 to the result from above and convert it to string
{        },                e# Now we have all possible strings of 1 to 9 with all possible
                           e# operators as well as joins (things like 567). Its time to
                           e# filter out what add up to 100
 ~                         e# Evaluate the string. This leaves some numbers on stack.
  ]:+                      e# Wrap those numbers in an array and take their sum
     100=                  e# Check if the sum is equal to 100
           N*              e# Join all filtered strings by newline
             S/'+*         e# We used space instead of +. So now we replace space with +
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22-%22SL%5D8m*%7BA%2C2%3E.%2B1%5C%2Bs%7D%25%7B%7E%5D%3A%2B100%3D%7D%2CN*S%2F%27%2B*)

Answer (score 3):

My shot at this:

## Python 2, 93 bytes

```
def a(e,i):
 if i<=9:[a(e+x+`i`,i+1)for x in("+","-","")]
 elif eval(e)==100:print e
a("1",2)
```

Comment: You can use single space indents and also `str(i) -> \`i\``. Also, you might want to mention that this is Python 2 specific :)

Comment: @Sp3000 Thanks!  I'm trying to improve my code golf skills and I'd never heard of the backtick thing.

Comment: One of the best code I have ever seen...

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
Print/@Select[""<>ToString/@Range@9~Riffle~#&/@{"+","-",""}~Tuples~{8},ToExpression@#==100&]
```

Fairly straightforward: generates all possible strings using `Tuples` and then filters them.

For reference, I get:

```
1+2+3-4+5+6+78+9
1+2+34-5+67-8+9
1+23-4+5+6+78-9
1+23-4+56+7+8+9
12+3+4+5-6-7+89
12+3-4+5+67+8+9
12-3-4+5-6+7+89
123+4-5+67-89
123+45-67+8-9
123-4-5-6-7+8-9
123-45-67+89
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
fqvT100m+ssC,r1Td9^c3"+-"8
```

First, we generate all 8 element combinations of ["+", "-", ""]. `c3"+-"` chops `"+-"` into 3 rougly equal sied pieces, giving the appropriate list. `^c3"+-"8` gives the 8 element combinations.

Then, we greate the arithmetic sequences. `C,r1Td` zips together the operators with the numbers 1 through 8, which are then summed twice to give the string, and `+ ... 9` puts a 9 at the end.

Finally, `fqvT100` filters for those expressions which evaluate to 100.

---

The update to the interpreter which allowed this code to work was [this one](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth/commit/3457185a1b1f7a85b23cd9135f8401e98edacdc9), which was made about a day before this question was asked, so this code would have only worked on the command line compiler, not the online one, when the question was asked.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqvT100m%2BssC%2Cr1Td9%5Ec3%22%2B-%228&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 86 <s>92</s>

Head to head with the best. That must be an anomalous problem.

**Edit** -6 thx @nderscore

```
for(i=6562;k=--i;eval(o)-100||alert(o))for(j=o=1;j++<9;k=k/3|0)o+=k%3?' +-'[k%3]+j:[j]
```

Test in any browser console, it pops up just 11 times.

Or this snippet:

```js
function out(x) { OUT.innerHTML = OUT.innerHTML + '\n' + x; }

// 6562 is 3 powered to 8 +1
for(i=6562;k=--i;eval(o)-100||out(o))
  for(j=o=1;j++<9;k=k/3|0)
    o+=k%3?' +-'[k%3]+j:[j]
```

```html
<pre id=OUT></pre>
```

Comment: Here's -6: `for(i=6562;k=--i;eval(o)^100||alert(o))for(j=o=1;9>j++;k=k/3|0)o+=k%3?' +-'[k%3]+j:[j]`

Comment: @nderscore thanks, some obvious changes against my sloppy golfing, but the last trick with the ternary is very clever

Answer (score 1):

## K, <s>61</s> 50 bytes

```
t@&100=.:'t:{:[x>9;,y;,/_f[x+1]'(y,"+";y,"-";y),\:$x]}[2;"1"]
```

Tested with Kona.

The general approach is to recursively generate all the expressions and then filter out those which eval (`.`) to 100. This is reasonably competitive as written, but I think there's still room for improvement.

### edit:

```
t@&100=.:'t:(,"1"){,/x,/:\:("+";"-";""),\:$y}/2+!8
```

Altering my approach a bit to be iterative rather than recursive, which removes the need for explicit base cases as well as saving me some brackets.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (176)

39 minutes and counting (for all problems that is)

```
from itertools import*
for i in product(('+','-',''),repeat=8):
 s=''.join(''.join(j)for j in chain(izip_longest(map(str,range(1,10)),i,fillvalue='')))
 if eval(s)==100:print s
```

This could probably be shorter, but this was my actual solution for this problem, just golfed down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>54 50</s></sup> 48 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
↑b/⍨100=⍎¨b←{' '~⍨,(1↓⎕D),⍪⍵,' '}¨(,∘.,)⍣7⍨'-+ '
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=e9Q2MUn/Ue8KQwMD20e9fYdWJD1qm1CtrqBeBxTU0TB81Db5Ud9UF02dR72rHvVu1QHK1B5aoaHzqGOGno7mo97F5kB16rraCuoA&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f)

A tradfn submission which uses strict right to left evaluation.